# Class 'Vinkla\Instagram\InstagramServiceProvider' not found Error

Tags: php, laravel, instagram

I am new to PHP and Laravel, my colleague installed InstagramServiceProvider in his project and he pushed it into git, after pulled the code i am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [a package](https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-instagram), so you need to install it on your machine too. Try to run `composer update` command and composer will download and install the package for you.